# Voice Coil/ Solenoid driver

Tags: dc, oscillator, solenoid

I am trying to figure out how to drive a solenoid/voice coil at 3V and 400-1000mA with a reciprocating output (forwards *and revers*e current) at around 50Hz **as cheaply as possible**. I have built some test coils and they work fine in terms of force at that wattage. I have considered a number of options for the driver, but am looking for some fresh, unbiased input. Let me know what you guys think!

EDIT: I am looking to use AA or AAA batteries to power the device. Thanks!

Comment: Please write a clear question, I see a few statements but no questions, it is generally good to write questions as this is a Q&A style forum. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

We have an application exactly like this we use to create a vibration for a motion test fixture, and we use an audio amplifier of the type used in automobiles to provide the bass boost.  You know the ones - they create the thumping that you hear from cars listening to loud music.  You can hook a function generator up to it and supply any waveform you want, and you can place a cap in series if you need to (we don't).  The one we have runs from 12 volts and cost about $80 new.

Answer (score 1):

If a 60Hz sine wave is close enough to your drive requirement, then simply using a power transformer to step down line voltage to 3V should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

If you live in a place with 50 Hz power, then you can step down that power with a transformer.  The transformer will also provide isolation, which will keep you and others from getting zapped.

Or, use a audio amplifier.  You can feed it 50 Hz from a signal generator, or make a small oscillator.  There are many ways to make such a small oscillator.  The oscillator provides the signal, and the audio amp provides the drive to put out 1 A at 3V.  Note that's only 3 W, but at 3 Ω impedance.  Most audio amplifiers can do that.